# 401 Unauthorized, SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, authentication, redux

Hi all I'm new to authentication. I was building an app where a user can login and create a story using an api, and the story is sent to the backend using a POST request. The app was authenticating fine, until I built the app. Now when I sign in and try to add a story, I get `401 Unauthorized` and `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` in actions.js.
Then if I refresh the page, the errors go away and the app is working.
I am able to logout and login again normally.
I have no idea why that's happening. Any help will be appreciated.
The backend server does say `Error in authorization JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed`

actions.js

```
import * as t from './actionTypes';
import { setUserSession } from '../utils/Common';
import { getToken } from '../utils/Common'


const token = getToken();

// this is what our action should look like which dispatches the "payload" to reducer
const setLoginState = (loginData) => {
  return {
    type: t.SET_LOGIN_STATE,
    payload: loginData, //{ ...json, userId: email }
  };
};

const setStoryState = (storyData) => {
    return {
      type: t.CREATE_STORY,
      payload: storyData, //storyData is the object with summary, description, type, etc.
    };
};

const getStoryState = (storyData) => {
  return {
    type: t.GET_STORIES,
    payload: storyData, //storyData is the object with summary, description, type, etc.
  };
};

const getSingleStoryState = (storyData) => {
  return {
    type: t.GET_STORY,
    payload: storyData, //storyData is the object with summary, description, type, etc.
  };
};

export const login = (loginInput) => { //our login action
    const { email, password, isAdmin } = loginInput;
    return (dispatch) => {  // don't forget to use dispatch here!
      return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {  
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(loginInput),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json()) //json will be the response body
        .then((json) => {
        // if (json.msg === 'success') { // response success checking logic could differ
           // console.log(json)
            dispatch(setLoginState({ ...json, userId: email, isAdmin: isAdmin })); // our action is called here with object as parameter, this is our payload
            //we appended json object to our state
            //   } else {
        //     alert('Login Failed', 'Email or Password is incorrect');
        //  }
            setUserSession(json.token, json.lastName)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert('Login Failed', 'Some error occured, please retry');
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
};

export const getStories = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {  // don't forget to use dispatch here!
      return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/stories', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {  
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json()) //json will be the response body
        .then((json) => {
        // if (json.msg === 'success') { // response success checking logic could differ
            console.log(json)
            dispatch(getStoryState( [...json ])); // our action is called here with object as parameter, this is our payload
            //we appended json object to our state
            //   } else {
        //     alert('Login Failed', 'Email or Password is incorrect');
        //  }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert('Login Failed', 'Some error occured, please retry');
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
}

export const viewStory = id => {
  return (dispatch) => {  // don't forget to use dispatch here!
      return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/stories/${id}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {  
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json()) //json will be the response body
        .then((json) => {
        // if (json.msg === 'success') { // response success checking logic could differ
            console.log(json)
            
            dispatch(getSingleStoryState( {...json } )); // our action is called here with object as parameter, this is our payload
            //we appended json object to our state
            //   } else {
        //     alert('Login Failed', 'Email or Password is incorrect');
        //  }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert('Login Failed', 'Some error occured, please retry');
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
}

export const roleChange = () => {
    return {
        type: t.SET_ROLE_STATE,
        //payload: role
      };
}

export const logout = () => {
  return {
    type: t.LOGOUT,
  };
}



export const createStory = storyInput => {
  console.log(token)
    const { summary, description, type, complexity, time, cost } = storyInput;
    return (dispatch) => {  // don't forget to use dispatch here!
      return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/stories', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {  
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(storyInput),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json()) //json will be the response body
        .then((json) => {
        // if (json.msg === 'success') { // response success checking logic could differ
            console.log(json)
            //dispatch(setStoryState( [...json ]));
            dispatch(setStoryState({  // our action is called here with object as parameter, this is our payload
                summary: summary,
                description: description,
                type: type,
                complexity: complexity,
                time: time,
                cost: cost
            })); // our action is called here
        //   } else {
        //     alert('Login Failed', 'Email or Password is incorrect');
        //  }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert('Some error occured, please retry');
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
}

export const addStory = story => {
    return {
        type: t.ADD_STORY,
        payload: story,
    }
}

export const setStatus = (id, status) => {
  return (dispatch) => {  // don't forget to use dispatch here!
      return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/stories/${id}/${status}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {  
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'text/html',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json()) //json will be the response body
        .then((json) => {
        // if (json.msg === 'success') { // response success checking logic could differ
            console.log(json)
            
         //   dispatch(getStoryState( {...json } )); // our action is called here with object as parameter, this is our payload
            //we appended json object to our state
            //   } else {
        //     alert('Login Failed', 'Email or Password is incorrect');
        //  }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert('Login Failed', 'Some error occured, please retry');
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
}
```

CreateStory.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { createStory } from '../redux/actions'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import history from '../utils/history';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const CreateStory = () => {

    const [summary, setSummary] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [type, setType] = useState("");
    const [complexity, setcomplexity] = useState("");
    const [time, setTime] = useState("");
    const [cost, setCost] = useState(0);

    const usedispatch = useDispatch();
    const userCreateStory = (summary, description, type, complexity) => usedispatch(createStory({
                                                                                    'summary': summary,
                                                                                    'description': description,
                                                                                    'type': type,
                                                                                    'complexity': complexity,
                                                                                    'time': time,
                                                                                    'cost': cost 
                                                                                }));

    const handleSummaryChange = e => {
        setSummary(e.target.value)
    }  
    
    const handleDescriptionChange = e => {
        setDescription(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleTypeChange = e => {
        setType(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleComplexityChange = e => {
        setcomplexity(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleTimeChange = e => {
        setTime(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleCostChange = e => {
        setCost(e.target.value)
    }

   // const currStory = useSelector((state)=> state.storyReducer.story)
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        userCreateStory(summary,description,type,complexity,time,cost)
        setTimeout(()=> history.push("/userStories"), 1000 );
      //setTimeout(()=> console.log(currStory) ,1000)
    }

    
    
    return (
        <div>
            <form className='create-story-form'>
                <label for="summary">Summary:</label>
                <input name="summary" type='text' onChange={handleSummaryChange}/>
                <label for="desc">Description:</label>
                <textarea name="desc" type='text' onChange={handleDescriptionChange}/>
                <label for="type">Type:</label>
                <select name="type" onChange={handleTypeChange}>
                    <option value="enhancement" defaultValue>Enchancement</option>
                    <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>
                    <option value="development">Development</option>
                    <option value="qa">QA</option>
                </select>
                <label for="complexity">Complexity:</label>
                <select name="complexity" onChange={handleComplexityChange}>
                    <option value="low" defaultValue>Low</option>
                    <option value="mid">Mid</option>
                    <option value="high">High</option>
                </select>
                <label for="time">Estimated time for completion:</label>
                <input name="time" type='text' onChange={handleTimeChange}/>
                <label for="cost">Cost:</label>
                <input name="cost" type='number' onChange={handleCostChange}/>
                <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(CreateStory);
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { login, roleChange } from '../redux/actions' //OUR ACTIONS
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import history from '../utils/history';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);

    const usedispatch = useDispatch();
    const userLogin = (email, password, isAdmin) => usedispatch(login({'email': email, 'password': password, 'isAdmin': isAdmin }));

    const handleRoleChange = e => {

        setIsAdmin(true)
        if(isAdmin)
            setIsAdmin(false)
        console.log(isAdmin)
    }
    
    const handleEmailChange = e => {
        setEmail(e.target.value)
    }

    const handlePasswordChange = e => {
        setPassword(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        userLogin(email, password, isAdmin)
        setTimeout(()=> history.push("/user"), 1000 );
    }

    const disabled = () => {
        return email === "" || password === ""
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form className='login-form'>
                <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email' onChange={handleEmailChange}/>
                <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' onChange={handlePasswordChange}/>
                <button type='submit' disabled={disabled()} onClick={handleSubmit}>Login</button>
            </form>
            <button onClick={handleRoleChange}>Switch to {isAdmin ? 'user' : 'admin'}</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

reducers.js

```
import { initialState } from './initialState';
import * as t from './actionTypes';

export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case t.SET_ROLE_STATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdmin: true
      };
    case t.SET_LOGIN_STATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload, // this is what we expect to get back from API call and login page input
        isLoggedIn: true, // we set this as true on login
      };
    case t.LOGOUT: 
      return {
        initialState
      };
    default:
      return state;
  } 
};

export const storyReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case t.CREATE_STORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        stories: [...state.stories, action.payload],
      };
    case t.GET_STORIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        stories: action.payload,
      };
    case t.GET_STORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        story: action.payload,
      };
    // case t.ADD_STORY:
    //   return {
    //     ...state,
    //     stories: [...state.stories, action.payload], //stories is an object
    //   };
    case t.LOGOUT:
      return {
        stories: [{complexity: "",
        cost: 0,
        description: "",
        summary: "",
        time: "",
        type: ""}]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  } 
}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` does not seem to be in the code posted?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no I haven't used that, since the app does work without it. I made a change to the question. When I refresh the page after the first login, the app works normally.